# Is it possible to turn an entire webpage to grayscale using CSS?

Tags: css, colors, grayscale

I would like to turn an entire website to grayscale. Of course, I can manually edit the CSS and adjust every single `color`, `background-color` & co. property, and I can adjust every single image in Photoshop.

But is there an easier way, e.g. by using pure CSS?

E.g., something such as putting a 100% x 100% overlay `div` on top of your site that turns every color to grayscale?

Any hints?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No need to set the filter on every single element, **You can apply the filter on HTML**.

```
html {
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

or body if you wish to keep a colored background on html.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLawaK

Comment: I think this is a better solution: doesn't break scrolling and DOM element positioning as accepted solution does and may be more efficient.

Comment: Why ‘html‘ and not just the ’body’?

Comment: @RoboRobok as said in the answer, one or the other, If set  body, then a colored background can be set on html in the case you still want to  use a bit of colors   (such as a red stripe or whatever else ... )

Answer (score 29):

Yes there is, just use filter grayscale

**CSS**

```
*{
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Note: You can apply this in any element (html, body, header, etc...)

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/19/)**

Comment: Uhm, maybe I am missing something, but even in your demo the logos are still colored, not grayscaled?

Comment: IMO `html { filter: grayscale(100%) }` should be better for performance.

Comment: @GoloRoden, maybe you need a prefix

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla IE version, please