# Is it possible to turn an entire webpage to grayscale using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my entire body tag to be at greyscale = 100% using javascript

like in css we can do it by using "*" selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to turn an entire webpage to grayscale using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192221/is-it-possible-to-turn-an-entire-webpage-to-grayscale-using-css)

Comment: Do you have a reason for not wanting to use css to do this?

Comment: yes actually in some of the cases i have to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select all elements, use `*` as well...

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"))
    .forEach(el => el.style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)');
```

However, if you just want to set grayscale on your page, use

```
document.body.style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select entire body:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
```